# How to count how many times a tag appear inside a CLOB PLSQL oracle 11g

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, oracle11g

i have a clob column in a table. In this clob i have a XML and i want to count how many times a tag appear inside this clob.

For example:

```xml
<TPQ>       
    <LTP>N<LTP> 
        <SUBLTP>N</SUBLTP>
        <TIMES>446</TIMES>
        <TIMES>321</TIMES>
        <TIMES>546</TIMES>
        <TIMES>547</TIMES>
    <LTP>N</LTP>    
    <LTP2>N<LTP2>   
        <SUBLTP>N</SUBLTP>
        <NODES>1</NODES>
        <NODES>2</NODES>
        <NODES>3</NODES>
        <NODES>4</NODES>
        <SUBLTP>H</SUBLTP>
        <SUBLTP3>A</SUBLTP3>
        <SUBLTP2>N</SUBLTP2>
    <LTP2>N</LTP2>  
</TPQ>
```

I want to know that the tag **`"TIMES"`** appears **4** times, and tag **`"NODES"`** appears **4** times.

Im using this query for getting all TIMES tag but i need know how to count:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(xmltype.createxml(T.columnCLOB), '//TPQ/LTP/TIMES').getStringVal()
  FROM table1 T;
```

and the result is this:

Result of the Select Statement is

```xml
<TIMES>446</TIMES><TIMES>321</TIMES><TIMES>546</TIMES><TIMES>547</TIMES>
```

This in a example, i need a solution for a dinamic clob column that can have x tags inside, not always with the same structure. But i only need to know how many times appears a specified tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```sql
SELECT t.id,
       x.tag_name,
       COUNT(*)
FROM   table_name t
       CROSS JOIN XMLTABLE(
         '//*'
         PASSING XMLTYPE(t.xml) 
         COLUMNS 
           tag_name varchar2(100) path 'name()'    
       ) x
GROUP BY t.id, x.tag_name
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (id NUMBER, xml CLOB);

INSERT INTO table_name (id, xml)
VALUES (1, '<TPQ>       
    <LTP>N</LTP> 
        <SUBLTP>N</SUBLTP>
        <TIMES>446</TIMES>
        <TIMES>321</TIMES>
        <TIMES>546</TIMES>
        <TIMES>547</TIMES>
    <LTP>N</LTP>    
    <LTP2>N</LTP2>   
        <SUBLTP>N</SUBLTP>
        <NODES>1</NODES>
        <NODES>2</NODES>
        <NODES>3</NODES>
        <NODES>4</NODES>
        <SUBLTP>H</SUBLTP>
        <SUBLTP3>A</SUBLTP3>
        <SUBLTP2>N</SUBLTP2>
    <LTP2>N</LTP2>  
</TPQ>');
```

Outputs:

> | ID | TAG_NAME | COUNT(*) |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | LTP | 2 |
> | 1 | LTP2 | 2 |
> | 1 | SUBLTP2 | 1 |
> | 1 | NODES | 4 |
> | 1 | TPQ | 1 |
> | 1 | SUBLTP | 3 |
> | 1 | TIMES | 4 |
> | 1 | SUBLTP3 | 1 |

---

If you only want a specific tag name and want to aggregate the tags' contents then:

```sql
SELECT t.id,
       x.tag_name,
       COUNT(*),
       LISTAGG(x.value, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY value) AS contents
FROM   table_name t
       CROSS JOIN XMLTABLE(
         '//TIMES'
         PASSING XMLTYPE(t.xml) 
         COLUMNS 
           tag_name VARCHAR2(100) PATH 'name()',
           value    VARCHAR2(4000) PATH 'text()'
       ) x
GROUP BY t.id, x.tag_name
```

Which outputs:

> | ID | TAG_NAME | COUNT(*) | CONTENTS |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | TIMES | 4 | 321,446,546,547 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=5aa711079224ba7234b12f7c4776beff)*

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer but i need a solution for a dinamic clob column that can have x tags inside, not always with the same structure. But i only need to know how many times appears a specified tag. And i would like to put in that table, the value inside the tag too, can you help me please with this.

Comment: @FreddyRicaurteLópez This will work for any CLOB as it will pull out **ALL** the tags. If you want to search for a specific tag then add a `WHERE` filter for that tag or change `//*` to `//TIMES`.

Comment: How can i do for not put  '<TPQ> <LTP>N</LTP> ' but VAR, where VAR is the string. something like this: INSERT INTO my_temp_table VALUES (1, VAR);

Answer (score 1):

XPATH functions can be used

```
with
  x as
    (select xmltype('<TPQ><LTP>N</LTP><SUBLTP>N</SUBLTP>
<TIMES>446</TIMES><TIMES>321</TIMES><TIMES>546</TIMES><TIMES>547</TIMES>
<LTP>N</LTP><LTP2>N</LTP2><SUBLTP>N</SUBLTP>
<NODES>1</NODES><NODES>2</NODES><NODES>3</NODES><NODES>4</NODES>
<SUBLTP>H</SUBLTP><SUBLTP3>A</SUBLTP3><SUBLTP2>N</SUBLTP2><LTP2>N</LTP2></TPQ>') xval
from dual)
select z.*
from x, xmltable ('count(/TPQ/TIMES)' passing x.xval) z;
```

Comment: When do that in a normal sql window it works, but when i do it inside a function it gives a 1 as result.

CODE:
 with x as
                        (select xmltype(T.INFO) xval
                        from INFOR T
                        WHERE T.ID = TYPE.ID)
                        select k
                        into V_CONT
                        from x, xmltable ('count(//TAG1/TAG2/TAG3/TAG4/TAG5)' passing x.xval) k;